# Observed this Error: Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Observed the error when tried to open a popper in grid table. Error Details

Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
The anchor element should be part of the document layout.
Make sure the element is present in the document or that it's not display none.

below is sample code I am using in grid table:

```
<>
    <MoreVertIcon
    ref={anchorRef}
    aria-controls={open ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
    aria-haspopup="true"
 // key={uuidv4()}
    onClick={handleToggle}
    style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.main }}
    />
    <Popper open={open} anchorEl={anchorRef.current} role={undefined} transition disablePortal>
        hello world
    </Popper>
</>
```

found a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493175/cant-get-popover-to-display-in-correct-position-in-dialog) but not sure where I am breaking this norm. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please reproduce your problem in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and then show the full code necessary to reproduce the problem in your question (along with the sandbox link). The cause is most likely in code that you are not showing which makes it difficult for anyone else to help.

Comment: This error happened to me when there was suspense state in the popper content. Wrapping the content in a suspense block fixed the problem.

Answer (score 18):

Finally got the reason, child component was re-rendering because I added dynamic key on map iteration which were causing props to change, as I used iteration index as key issue resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Another way that this error can occur is when using a react `ref`. There can be a 'race condition' where the element is created before it is rendered, it can be solved by delaying setting the anchor by a frame:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const anchorRef = React.useRef()
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState()
    React.useEffect(() => { 
        setTimeout(() => setAnchorEl(anchorRef?.current), 1) 
    },  [anchorRef])

    return <div ref={anchorRef}>
        {anchorEl && <Popper anchorEl={anchorEl}>hello world</Popper>}
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error using the Menu component from MUI `5.13.6` because I was simply missing the `anchorEl` property, even though the component was behaving correctly.

```js
const [anchorEl, setMenuAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
const menuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

<Menu
  open={menuOpen}
  onClick={handleClose}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}  // 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my scenario is the same as the OP, and I haven't found a solution, but I was getting this warning because I was using a MUI `IconButton` as a Tooltip and the Icon would change based on the user's selection in the tooltip. Since the IconButton that the tooltip is anchored to re-renders, it throws the error. Changing `GridVariantIcon` to just use a specific MUI Icon removes the error but also does not achieve my desired behavior (the icon reflecting the current selection).

```
const renderGridSelection = () => (
    <IconButton aria-label="grid selection" color="primary">
        <HtmlTooltip
            title={renderGridSelections()}
            placement="right"
        >
            <GridVariantIcon variant={gridVariant} />
        </HtmlTooltip>
    </IconButton>
);
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case the issue was due to the fact my button `IconButton` was not receiving the actual `ref={anchorRef}`. Yep, that silly issue...

Also, in my case, I could do well with a name key other than an index like:

```
{optionsArray.map(option => (
     <MenuItem key={option} onClick={handleClose}>
          {option}
     </MenuItem>
))}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but my `IconButton` does have the `anchorRef` and I'm still getting this warning. Can you show how you changed it in code?